# How to detect that UIScrollView is scrolling or that is is dragging

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to know on a continuous basis when my UIScrollView is scrolling or dragging.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Implement these two delegate methods..

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{
  //executes when you scroll the scrollView
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
 // execute when you drag the scrollView
}
```

Comment: for new folks (me) may need to declare scroll view delegate to get code above to work -> '@interface ViewController : UIViewController < UIScrollViewDelegate>'   // (thank you Shorhashi)

Comment: "executes when you scroll the scrollView" - is not entirely true, if user is "you". Programmatically moving the scrollview will call `scrollViewDidScroll:` too.

Answer (score 22):

Better use `isTracking` to detect if the user initiated a touch-drag.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.isTracking {   
    // ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

*This answer is deprecated. See @ober's **isTracking** solution instead*

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{
    if(sender.isDragging) {
        //is dragging
    }
    else {
        //is just scrolling
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer. When your finger lift up from the screen, isDragging still being YES, this may not be what you expect.

Comment: scrollView.isTracking is the correct answer as per ober's answer below.