# How to judge the direction of the UIScrollView is going to scroll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

**Note**:My question is the direction of the scrollView **will** scroll,not scrolling.That is to say,when user scroll the scrollView,can we get the direction of the scrollView is going to scroll before the scrollView begin scrolling?

Any idea?Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797005/detect-if-uiscrollview-is-scrolling

Comment: see this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015898/how-to-detect-that-uiscrollview-is-scrolling-or-that-is-is-dragging

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using scroll view delegate you can identify.

**Objective C :**

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint point = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];
    if (point.y > 0) {
        // Dragging down
    } else {
        // Dragging up
    }
}
```

**Swift :**

```
 func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let actualPosition = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
        if (actualPosition.y > 0){
            // Dragging down
        }else{
            // Dragging up
        }
    }
```

Comment: as question tagged with `objective c` you should write your answer in `objective c`!

Comment: @Lion Thanks for the info. I have updated the answers.

Comment: Now it's better!